# Why can't I load this specific PNG into my QPixmap?

Tags: c++, qt, png, openstreetmap, qpixmap

Why can't I load this png into my QPixmap?
[Open street map png](http://otile2.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/osm/8/137/79.png)

```
Q_ASSERT(fakeMap.load("C:/map71.png"));
```

This renders an ASSERT.

Does not render an ASSERT if I open it in MS paint and re saves it either as a jpeg or png (but larger in size). Same path and syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image you link to is actually a JPEG.  If I save it with the jpg extension it loads into Qt ok.  Qt is probably trying to treat it as a PNG and that's why it's failing.

Comment: You are right.. This also works: Q_ASSERT(fakeMap.load("79.png", "jpg"));

Comment: Maybe Qt should be able to scan the image header in a better way and not just rely on the file extension?

Comment: According to [QPixmap documentation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qpixmap.html#load), the format _is_ tried to guess from the header. But it seems that the guessing is not perfect.